# MySQL select column name and value as a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that looks something like this:

```
id | PO | DAP   | MEDIA
---|----|-------|------
1  | 2  | 34    | 64
2  | 6  | 53    | 23
```

I would like to be able to query get multiple rows, one for each column. E.g:

```
SELECT column_name as column, column_value as value FROM my_table;
```

Which would give me:

```
PO=2,DAP=34,MEDIA=54,PO=6,DAP=53,MEDIA=23
```

What would I need to use to formulate a query like this?

Comment: I don't see the problem, even `select * from my_table` will give you exactly the requested result. Formatting it specifically like that is your own code's responsibility, not MySQL's, so do that in PHP or C# or whatever you're using.

Comment: This is called a pivot table query - but why not handle the display logic at the application level, e.g. with a simple PHP loop.

Comment: `SELECT PO, DAP, MEDIA FROM YOUR_TABLE` have you tried this?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT('PO=', PO) AS PO_value ... ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first `CONCAT` the data of each specified field and apply `GROUP_CONCAT` ON the result.

**Query**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(temp_col) FROM
(
    SELECT 1 as 'temp_id',
    CONCAT(
      CONCAT('PO=', PO),
      ',',
      CONCAT('DAP=', DAP),
      ',',
      CONCAT('MEDIA=', MEDIA)
    ) AS 'temp_col'
    FROM test
) temp
GROUP BY temp_id
```

Check Out **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11769/15)**

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean. But this is traditionally done in this manner

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

You'll get your array like this

```
array(0=>array('PO'=>2,'DAP'=>34,'MEDIA'=54), 1=>array('PO'=>6, 'DAP'=>53, 'MEDIA'=> 23))
```

.. like so.